# sublime text 2 macOSX double quote issue

Tags: macos, parsing, text-editor, sublimetext2, double-quotes

When I do shift key + single/double quote key on my mac using Sublime Text 2 I don't get parseable double quotes.

Here's a picture demonstrating the effect on the `id=""`'s of some HTML:
[image]

Does anyone know how to correct this? The correct double-quotes were generated by a different text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. I had installed [Sublime's Zencoding plugin](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=580&sid=5c094c6ad7387e459a34e97e3c14308c#p10654) which when I removed it, the double-quotes were normal again.

**Update:** Oddly, this double-quote issue still exists in my PHP files, but not my JS files. I'm not sure how to solve this yet but will update this answer when I do.

**UPDATE #2** 
I finally solved the PHP file double-quote issue. Please see [my answer on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960270/sublime-text-2-double-quote-font-style-depends-on-file-extension/15032320#15032320).

I had a a key binding set to use these "typographical" quotes in my SublimeText2 `preferences->key bindings->user`