# Sublime Text 2 double quote font-style depends on file extension?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

The auto-pairing of double quotes is a really strange issue [that I thought I'd solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521058/sublime-text-2-macosx-double-quote-issue) but still persists. The issue is that for files of the extension .php, .html, the default font-style of auto-paired double quotes is not parseable. To show you what I mean, notice the font-style of the double quotes in the `<div>` on the left. Whereas with .js and .css files, the double quote auto-pairing has the proper font-style as shown in the `<div>` on the right>.

This must be a setting somewhere but I don't know Sublime Text2 (Mac OSX) so well. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's another plugin that has altered the keymap for Shift? Have you tried looking at the keymaps of all non-default packages?

Comment: @JamieJag thanks, can you tell me how to do that? I'm a novice with Sublime

Comment: It's a tedious process - go to Preferences->Browse Packages, and in each of the folders listed there that you can identify as packages that you installed, look in 'Default (OSX).sublime-keymap' for shift+' or shift+".

Comment: thanks, dangit i can't find anything in my sublime-keymap files. I only have a couple packages so it wasn't that bad. I see a potential problem being that these files are all in JSON which is a file type where the double quotes render properly. Maybe PHP files aren't UTF-8 encoded or something? I don't even know what you call these alternate double quotes. As an alternative solution, is there a way to assign some other key combination to the double quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the huge help from @JamieJag I've isolated the problem. Shift+" was producing what Sublime calls **"typographical"** quotes and not the double quotes which are parseable as part of PHP or HTML code.

To fix the problem, I commented out everything in my SublimeText2 preferences->key bindings->user.

It's unclear to me whether one or all of these JSON object is responsible for the problematic behavior (though I'd guess the first JSON looks like the offender) but so far just commenting out the entire array solved my problem.

```
/*[

// Auto-pair typographical quotes
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "“$0”"}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|”|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text", "match_all": true }
   ]
},
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "“${0:$SELECTION}”"}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text", "match_all": true }
   ]
},
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\”", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text", "match_all": true }
   ]
},
// Smart quotes before & after word
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "“$0"}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\S", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text", "match_all": true }
   ]
},
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "”$0"}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\S", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text", "match_all": true }
   ]
}

]*/
```

Comment: it seems that all you need to do is turn off the setting "auto_match_enabled" to 'false' in your settings since all these key mappings seem to come into effect only when it's set to true